# What is the difference between various TPM modules?

Tags: compatibility, tpm

I was looking for a TPM 2.0 module for my Gigabyte Z87MX-D3H and I found that [the brand of the module is not important](https://sites.google.com/site/techbobbins/home/articles/gigabyte-motherboard-tpm-compatibility).

The ones I found are:

- [ASUS TPM-M R2.0](https://uk.store.asus.com/components/accessories/motherboards/asus-trusted-platform-module-tpm-m-r2-0-securely-stores-keys-data-passwords.html) 14 pin
- [Asus TPM-L R2.0](https://uk.store.asus.com/components/accessories/motherboards/asus-trusted-platform-module-tpm-l-r2-0-securely-stores-keys-data-passwords.html) 20 pin
- Asus Trusted Platform Module TPM/FW3.19 (20 pins)
- Gigabyte TPM Module GC-TPM2.0 (20 pins)

What is the difference among the first three? I guess the last one is identical to the second one, but I cannot find any information about the TPM/FW3.19 vs the TPM-L, both 20 pins.

Comment: "What is the difference among the first three?" - The brand and the number of pins the module has.  *I guess that the 14 pins is not compatible.* - That would be correct.  *what is the recommended one?* - **This question is not on topic here at Superuser, please edit your question, and remove it from your question.**

Comment: @Ramhound I removed the question, leaving only the question about the differences. I clarified that the biggest unknown is between the FW3.19 and the other 20 pin one. Also, all the first three are from the same brand.

Comment: You have no really provided any information on any of the choices though.  It is very unlikely the ASUS TPMs are going to work on a Gigabyte motherboard.

Comment: @Ramhound well now the question is about the differences between the modules and I put the links to the ASUS website, that is the best I can do. I also added, for info, a link with a first-hand experience of a person using ASUS modules on a Gigabyte motherboard. Also, I'm not surprised the chip has a standard interface and is compatible with multiple mobos.

Comment: The only two product pages you linked to, didn't actually work for me, searches for working pages indicate very little difference between those two products which indicate they are likely very similar except for the number of pins.  I found no specifics on [Asus Trusted Platform Module TPM/FW3.19](https://www.amazon.com/Asus-Accessory-TPM-L-R2-0-Motherboard/dp/B01EU542SG) except for the fact it works with your motherboard and there is likely no differences between it and the Asus TPM-L R2.0

Comment: @Ramhound yes they are uncommon products with little information available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TPM/FW3.19 is TPM 1.2 compatible and TPM-L R2.0 is 2.0 compatible.

Ok, let me explain again. TPM/FW3.19 (20 pins) is an old module created for old Motherboards like P8B, P9D etc. and it's TPM 1.2 compatible. Asus TPM-L R2.0 20 pin replaces TPM/FW3.19 and is for newer MB like X99-based and it supports TPM 2.0. The last one, ASUS TPM-M R2.0 is for Skylake or later motherboards and it supports TMP 2.0.  If you have an old MB with 20-1 connector probably Asus TPM-L R2.0 20 pin will not be compatible with it, it depends on BIOS. You have to check it with your vendor. I guess you understand that you can't use 14 pin module on 20 pin motherboard or vice versa.

Comment: Skylake and later Intel processors almost all have TPM 2.0 built in, possibly shown as Platform Trust Technology or PTT in the BIOS.

Answer (score 8):

The naming of pluggables TPM-cards should be something like
TPM-L-R2.0, where the L stands for the pins and it's spacing and the R for the protocoll revision.

Please note that on the mechnical part there at least 3 different types. 
See as well for the electrical part: [LowPinCount-Bus (LPC bus)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Pin_Count).

1. pincount (14pins for M, 19 out of 20 pins for L, 17 out of 18 pins for S)
2. pinspacing: 2,54mm for TPM-L and 2mm for TPM-S.
   TPM-S has the "ident-pin" (the "missing one/stuffed hole") on 3rd last column, TPM-L has the ident pin on the 2nd last column.

Answer (score 2):

The Motherboard Manual will tell you exactly the TPM Module needed, e.g., mine is one you have not mentioned here, TPM-SPI.

It also tells you on the motherboard where the pins are, what version is needed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The description in the link for the Asus TPM-L R2.0 [supposed] 20 pin states the TPM  is a 14-1 package.
There's all sorts of faff with Infineon TPMs and Windows updates the last few months.