# What in millimeters is the pin pitch for a 14-1 aka TPM-M connector?

Tags: tpm, pin

Without disassembling enough of my two running self-built desktop PCs to be able to measure them in millimeters, I'm trying to find out the spacing of the pins on the standard TPM-M (also called 14-1 because one pin is blocked) motherboard connector.  It's likely either 2.54mm, 2.0mm, or 1.27mm - I think.  I have no discrete TPM modules, connected or unconnected, to take measurements from instead.

I've tried Googling but I haven't had any 100% positive luck.  The closest I found is the top search result from this [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?sa=N&sxsrf=ALeKk00fVup5kb75uPHxvTEqvvQ-iHBtcg:1628105394033&q=14-pin%20tpm%20%22pitch%22&ved=2ahUKEwjf5KudjZjyAhWVZs0KHfinDBs4ChDm3gJ6BAgDEBM&biw=2560&bih=1247), which when followed leads [here](https://www.chinasuppliers.globalsources.com/china-suppliers/TPM-Pin-Header.htm), at which the top result is for [2.54mm Pin header Double Row Pin Header Right Angle S.M.T Type](https://www.globalsources.com/Pin-header/female-header-pin-header-male-header-box-header-1174217817p.htm#1174217817), however, the second Google search result leads [here](https://www.globalsources.com/products/TPM-Pin-Header.html) (same site) on which the second item listed is [1.27 Pitch Dual Rows Pin Header - H1.0 Right angle type pin header connector - P/N.Y01410-12R-RA-XP](https://www.globalsources.com/Pin-header/1-27-Pin-Header-Righ-angle-pin-header-pin-header-1180603964p.htm#1180603964).

I'm not trying to buy any of these items - I'm trying to find the correct pitch in order to either buy or build the correct short extension cable since I have an obtrusive card in the PCIe slot which would likely interfere with using a discreet TPM module and moving the card to another position isn't an option.  This particular desktop doesn't have a processor with a built-in TPM either.

Also, I would likely encase the TPM module, once I get one for a not crazy price.

Cheers and thank you!

Update 1:  The (not what I'm looking for) 20-pin TPM connector pin spacing appears to be 2.54mm, as evidenced [here](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/evaluation-boards/tpm-65-xenonboard/), which doesn't mean anything except just another piece of data.

Update 2:
I've come a little closer to what I was looking for.  I decided to try [re-wording my Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=spacing%20between%20pins%20on%2014-1%20tpm&oq=spacing%20between%20pins%20on%2014-1%20tpm&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i160l2.7895j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) once more, and lo and behold, the answer was the second search hit leading right back here to superuser.com.  The second to the last answer by @user2850988, currently with 5 upvotes, has related information, [but sadly the spacings listed are only for TPM-L and TPM-S, not TPM-M](https://superuser.com/a/1397949/684218):

> Please note that on the mechnical part there at least 3 different
> types. See as well for the electrical part: LowPinCount-Bus (LPC bus).
>
> pincount (14pins for M, 19 out of 20 pins for L, 17 out of 18 pins for S)
>
> **pinspacing: 2,54mm for TPM-L and 2mm for TPM-S**. TPM-S has the
> "ident-pin" (the "missing one/stuffed hole") on 3rd last column, TPM-L
> has the ident pin on the 2nd last column.
>
> edited Jan 24 '19 at 20:35 zx485
>
> answered Jan 24 '19 at 15:20 [user2850988](https://superuser.com/users/549391/user2850988?tab=profile)

Comment: You are aware that every processor that supports Windows 11 supports a fTPM that all AMD and Intel supported processors support?  Outside of that, your motherboard likely supports only specific discrete TPM, knowing the pin pitch won’t be helpful.

Comment: This is not regarding Windows 11, and the desktop in question doesn't have a processor that supports fTPM.  This motherboard supports TPM-M, also known as 14-1 for the overall pin count, minus one pin in a particular place that's blocked on the appropriate add-on TPM module.  I'm aware of the TPM-M (14-1) type TPM modules I have a choice from to buy.  The problem is that I need to use a cable to go between the motherboard and the TPM module, to physically bypass a PCIe card that I have in a slot right next to the TPM-M connector on the motherboard.  I need to know the spacing to get correct 1.

Comment: What is the make and model of the motherboard in question?

Comment: Thanks Andrew, the answer is MSI X99A SLI Krait Edition (I believe MS-7885), although I left it out of the original question on purpose because the answer will likely apply to all 14-1 connectors on all manufacturer's motherboards.  They seem to all be the same physically, not counting that Asus has an additional 14-1 motherboard connector that has the blocked pin in a different spot, but a cable that worked as an extension on one will likely work as an extension on many different manufacturer's motherboards.  In my case, I still have to use an MSI 14-1 TPM-M module MS-4136.

Comment: I wish there was some way to get @user2850988 's attention, although they might not know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

On my Asus motherboard it has half the spacing of the USB headers next to it.
USB headers are certainly 2.54 mm, so 1.27 mm is the answer.

Obviously I don't know if there are variants with other spacing. Your motherboards might be different.
It is next to impossible to find this information online for the 14-pin TPM header. (The 20-pin has a spin-spacing indicator as suffix in the name.)

Comment: Hi @Tonny.  Would you mind letting me know which Asus motherboard model you have?  Thank you!

Comment: I've got a Asus Prime X470-Pro. I was trying to find a 14-1 TPM myself and I also discovered what a mess this is... (My Ryzen has fTPM, but I prefer a discrete one. fTPM can loose keys during a Bios update which would really suck in my case.)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the information.  I don't know if this is allowed, but this is the best bet I've found for Asus' TPM-M module:  https://www.shopblt.com/cgi-bin/shop/shop.cgi?action=thispage&thispage=01100300U033_B3F8915P.shtml&order_id=757540126&sitem=B3F8915.  $10.82 U.S., 5,504 pre-ordered by users, and they have 6,540 stock incoming, and expected ETA for an order today is 9/20/2021.  Note this is changing fast as 24 hours ago ETA was 9/4.  I don't feel completely secure that the 14-1 TPM-M connector has half the spacing of USB headers - maybe 2.0mm so I'll wait for other confirmation.

Comment: @Tonny Your answer is incorrect. TPM-M headers have a pitch size of 2.0mm. Please do not state your answer authoritatively when you're making a speculation.